# Relying on rule order

Tags: prolog, meta-predicate

To calculate the hamming distance between two lists of the same length, I use `foldl(hamm, A, B, 0, R).` with this definition of `hamm/4`:

```
hamm(A, A, V, V) :- !.
hamm(A, B, V0, V1) :- A \= B, V1 is V0 + 1.
```

The cut in the first rule prevents the unnecessary backtracking. The second rule, however, could have been written differently:

```
hamm2(A, A, V, V) :- !.
hamm2(_, _, V0, V1) :- V1 is V0 + 1.
```

and `hamm2/4` will still be correct together with `foldl/5` or for queries where both A and B are ground.

So is there a really good reason to prefer the one over the other? Or is there a reason to keep the rules in that order or switch them around?

I know that the query

```
hamm(a, B, 0, 1).
```

is false, while

```
hamm2(a, B, 0, 1).
```

is true, but I can't quite decide which one makes more sense . . .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You already spotted the differences between those definitions: efficiency apart, you should decide about your requirements. Are you going to accept variables in your data structures? Such programming style introduces some of advanced Prolog features (incomplete data structures).

Anyway, I think the first form is more accurate (not really sure about, I would say *steadfast on 4° argument*)

```
?- hamm(a, B, 0, 1).
false.

?- hamm(a, B, 0, 0).
B = a.
```

while hamm2 is

```
?- hamm2(a, B, 0, 1).
true.

?- hamm2(a, B, 0, 0).
B = a.
```

Comment: You could argue, for `hamm2(a, B, 0, 1)`, yes, B is not the same as A, so these two elements should add to the hamming distance... but as I said, I also can't quite decide when this would make sense.

Answer (score 2):

The OP implemented two accumulator-style predicates for calculating the Hamming distance (`hamm/4` and `hamm2/4`), but wasn't sure which one made *more* sense.

Let's read the query that puzzled the OP: "Is there an X such that distance(a,X) is 1?". Here are the "answers" Prolog gives:

```
?- hamm(a,X,0,1). 
false.                          % wrong: should succeed conditionally
?- hamm2(a,X,0,1).              % wrong: should succeed, but not unconditionally
true.
```

From a logical perspective, *both* implementations misbehave in above test. Let's do a few tests for *steadfastness*:

```
?- hamm(a,X,0,1),X=a.           % right
false.
?- hamm(a,X,0,1),X=b.           % wrong: should succeed as distance(a,b) is 1
false.

?- hamm2(a,X,0,1),X=a.          % wrong: should fail as distance(a,a) is 0
X = a.
?- hamm2(a,X,0,1),X=b.          % right 
X = b.
```

Note that in previous queries `hamm/4` rightly fails when `hamm2/4` wrongly succeeded, and vice-versa.
So *both* are half-right/half-wrong, and *neither* one
is steadfast.

---

*What can be done?*

Based on `if_/3` and `(=)/3` presented by @false in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27358600/4609915), I implemented the following pure code for predicate `hamm3/4`:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

hamm3(A,B,V0,V) :-
   if_(A = B, V0 = V, V #= V0+1).
```

Now let's repeat above queries using `hamm3/4`:

```
?- hamm3(a,X,0,1). 
dif(X,a).
?- hamm3(a,X,0,1),X=a.
false.
?- hamm3(a,X,0,1),X=b.
X = b.
```

*It works!*  Finally, let's ask the *most general query* to see the entire solution set of  `hamm3/4`:

```
?- hamm3(A,B,N0,N).
A = B,    N0 = N ;
dif(A,B), N0+1 #= N.
```