# Implement a Prolog predicate that say if an element belong to a list. Problems with not numerical lists

Tags: prolog, prolog-dif

I am studying Prolog for an university exam and I have problems with this exercise:

> Implement the predicate `not_member(X,L)` that is TRUE if the element `X` does not belong to the list `L`.

If my reasoning is correct, I have found a solution:

```
% FACT (BASE CASE): It is TRUE that X is not in the list if the list is empty.
not_member(_,[]).

% RULE (GENERAL CASE): If the list is non-empty, I can divide it in its Head
%   element and the sublist Tail. X does not belong to the list if it is different 
%   from the current Head element and if it does not belong to the sublist Tail.
not_member(X,[Head|Tail]) :-
   X =\= Head,
   not_member(X,Tail).
```

This code works well with lists of numbers, as the following queries show:

```
2 ?- not_member(4, [1,2,3]).
true.

3 ?- not_member(1, [1,2,3]).
false.
```

With lists having some non-numerical elements, however,
it does not work and reports an error:

```
4 ?- not_member(a, [a,b,c]).
ERROR: =\=/2: Arithmetic: `a/0' is not a function
```

Why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's check the documentation!

[(=\=)/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=%28=%5C=%29/2) is an arithmetic operator.

> +Expr1 =\= +Expr2
>       True if expression Expr1 evaluates to a number non-equal to Expr2.

You have to use [(\=)/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=%28%5C=%29/2) to compare two generic terms:

```
not_member(_, []) :- !.

not_member(X, [Head|Tail]) :-
     X \= Head,
    not_member(X, Tail).
```

and:

```
?- not_member(d, [a,b,c]).
true.
```

Comment: ok, tnx so much. Only a litle clarification: why do you use: not_member(_, []) :- !. instead: not_member(_, []). 
what exactly mean !. ?

Tnx

Comment: (not a detailed explanation) It's a cut. It prevents backtracking, but it's not mandatory. In this case it's ok to use it since once the unification has succeded on not_member(_, []). we don't need to check for other "solutions", so we "cut" the prolog search tree and stop che computation.

Answer (score 5):

Use [prolog-dif](/questions/tagged/prolog-dif) to get **logically sound answers**—for *both* ground *and* non-ground cases!

Just like [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10322639/4609915), we define `non_member(E,Xs)` as `maplist(dif(E),Xs)`.

Let's put `maplist(dif(E),Xs)` and [`not_member(E,Xs)`  by @Haile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15865303/4609915) to the test!

```
?- not_member(E,[1,2,3]).
false.                                   % wrong! What about `E=4`?

?- maplist(dif(E),[1,2,3]).
dif(E,1), dif(E,2), dif(E,3).            % success with pending goals
```

Is it steadfast? (For more info on this important issue, read
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14556019/4609915), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30827427/4609915), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15710541/4609915), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29888591/4609915) answer.)

```
?- E=d, not_member(E,[a,b,c]).
E = d.
?-      not_member(E,[a,b,c]), E=d.
false.                                  % not steadfast

?- E=d, maplist(dif(E),[a,b,c]).
E = d.
?-      maplist(dif(E),[a,b,c]), E=d.   % steadfast
E = d.
```

Let's not forget about the most general use!

```
?- not_member(E,Xs).               
Xs = [].                                % a lot of solutions are missing!

?- maplist(dif(E),Xs).
  Xs = []
; Xs = [_A]      , dif(E,_A)
; Xs = [_A,_B]   , dif(E,_A), dif(E,_B)
; Xs = [_A,_B,_C], dif(E,_A), dif(E,_B), dif(E,_C)
...
```